# Zero point of uniformly convergent maps

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Assume $S\colon B_1(0)\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$, where $B_1(0)$ is the unit ball of $\mathbb R^n$, and 
$$
S(x)=Ax
$$
where $A$ is a given $n\times n$ matrix.  Besides, continue maps $S_\varepsilon\colon B_1(0)\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ uniformly converge to $S$ on $B_1(0)$ as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$. What is the weakest condition make the $S_\varepsilon$ has zero point for small enough $\varepsilon$ ?

In fact, when $\lvert A\rvert \ne0$, I feel, for small enough $\varepsilon$, $S_\varepsilon$ will has zero point. But I think this condition is too  strong, seemly, just $a_{11}\ne0$ is enough, but I don't know how to show it.

After some test, only $a_{11}\ne0$ is not  enough.

Comment: What do you mean by a **zero point**?

Comment: What’s $S_\varepsilon$?

Comment: @user539887 $\exists x_0\in B_1(0)$ such that $S_\varepsilon (x_0)=0$, where $0$ is the origin of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @JonWarneke $S_\varepsilon$ has not  concrete form, just uniformly converge to $S$.

Comment: There is a whole branch of mathematics, called [Topological Degree Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_continuous_mapping#Maps_from_closed_region), which deals with such (and related) problems.

Comment: @user539887  In fact, according degree theory, $|A|$ must be non-zero.